# Application can't find libc++_shared.so

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, dependencies

I am using a native library to do complex calculations for my application. When I run the application on newer more high end devices, the application runs fantastically. However, when I run it on devices such as the Blu Dash, lenovo tablet or Alcatel One touch the application can't link with the native library because we have an unresolved dependency with `libc++_shared.so'

Why would libc++ be present on the former devices and not the latter? Is a possible resolution to dump libc++ into my natives folder?

Edit:
My newer devices are the S3, S4 and Nexus 7 all running 4.4.2. The older devices are running sub 4.2. This fact may be much more relevant than I think.

Comment: Did you find the solution

Comment: @ZuzooVn Ya, I was using the incorrect compiler toolchain. I dug more into Android's NDK cross-compile tool chain and made the correct binary. Worked just fine.