# Clang linking .so library libc++_shared.so

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang

I'm having an Error in my Native C++ Code in Android NDK Application

My main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  printf("Hello, world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The main.c is exactly the same.
If i run

```
/home/rip/Music/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android26-clang -pie main.c
```

then

```
adb push a.out /data/local/tmp
```

and

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/a.out
```

all works fine. But if i run

```
/home/rip/Music/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android26-clang++ -pie main.cpp
```

then

```
adb push a.out /data/local/tmp
```

and

```
 adb shell /data/local/tmp/a.out
```

The error message is:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/local/tmp/a.out": library "libc++_shared.so" not found
```

Then i tried to run

```
/home/rip/Music/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android26-clang++ -pie hello1.cpp  /home/rip/Music/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/libc++_shared.so
```

to link the library, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Maybe use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a new Answer for the Solution because i cannot edit my question. 
The Solution is the following command for android devices with armv7:

```
/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot main.cpp
```

For aarch64 armv8 the command is:

```
/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot main.cpp
```

A CMakeLists.txt file should look as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++)

project(Test CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot")

set(SOURCES
        main.cpp
        )

add_executable(Test ${SOURCES})
```

Then can the app build with

```
cmake

make

adb push Test /data/local/tmp

adb shell /data/local/tmp/Test
```

Comment: You should never need to configure these things manually. If you're using the NDK's CMake toolchain file all of this is already handled for you. If you needed to do this then you're invoking CMake incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

> The error message is:
>
> ```
> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/local/tmp/a.out": library "libc++_shared.so" not found
> ```

That's the expected behavior. Unlike the standard C library (to which your program is linking when building with simple `*-clang`), C++ is not a system library. You have to make it available on the device just like any other third party library.

Quoted from [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support):

> **Note:** libc++ is not a system library. If you use **libc++_shared.so**, it must be included in your APK. If you're building your application with Gradle this is handled automatically.

And:

> If you're using clang directly in your own build system, clang++ will use `c++_shared` by default. To use the static variant, add `-static-libstdc++` to your linker flags.

So either link with C++ statically by passing `-static-libstdc++` to compiler. Or copy the `libc++_shared.so` (from `<NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/` in your case) and run like:

```
adb push a.out libc++_shared.so /data/local/tmp/
adb shell
cd /data/local/tmp/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

Other than the LLVM's Standard C++ library discussed above, there's also a limited system C++ runtime (`/system/lib(64)/libstdc++.so`) which *"provides support for the basic C++ Runtime ABI"*. But *"The system STL will be removed in a future NDK release."*

Comment: I'm not sure about location of libc++_shared.so. I think that proper file is `<NDK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/libc++_shared.so`

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the same "hello world" code in a .c and .cpp file and didn't have the same issue when I pushed the application to my device. I assume you're having the same issue as in this topic:
[Application can't find libc++_shared.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621452/application-cant-find-libc-shared-so)
The issue may come from your toolchain or toolchain parameters as you are calling clang manually.

I created a simple project that you can run and test:
[android-ndk-example](https://github.com/hichem/android-ndk-example)

```
add_executable( # Sets the name of the library.
    ndk_example_c

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    main.c
    )


add_executable( # Sets the name of the library.
        ndk_example_cpp

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        main2.cpp
        )
```

In generated cmake script, I can see the following definition for cpp compiler:

```
 rule CXX_COMPILER__ndk_example_cpp
  depfile = $DEP_FILE
  deps = gcc
  command = D:\Users\$USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=D:/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=D:/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  $DEFINES $INCLUDES $FLAGS -MD -MT $out -MF $DEP_FILE -o $out -c $IN_ABS
  description = Building CXX object $out
```

Comment: I doesn't worked with gradle before. How can i compile this project?

Comment: You can open the project in android studio, have an sdk and ndk installed, and then run Build > Rebuild Project. The binaries will be generated in app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a

Comment: Thanks it works. Can i also use qml instead of the java gui?

Comment: Yes, I did that few years ago. I was using Android.mk at the time. Just try to check how to configure your qt android project with gradle and cmake.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it to my answer once I am back home :-) thanks!